# Using Angular6 I want to call Logout() function only when browser tab / browser close button is clicked not page refresh

Tags: angular

I have a requirement in my app where i want to call Logout() function only when browser tab / browser close button is clicked using angular6.

Not when page navigation, page refresh.

I have used onbefeunload and onunload. but it is not working properly.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `AuthGuard` do this: https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3

Comment: I think you can leverage `sessionStorage` for this and combine it with `AuthGuard`. I believe it is much simpler and stable solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the `window:unload` event.

```
export class AppComponent {
    @HostListener('window:unload', [ '$event' ])
    unloadHandler(event) {
       // Runs whenever the user closes tab or browser
    }
```

Keep in mind that there's certain restrictions in what kind of code you can run during this event. One example is an alert box -- this will never be shown when the tab is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement window unload method conditionally something like,

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var y = e.pageY || e.clientY;
    if (y < 0) {
 console.log("Here you have to call logout.");            
    } 
}
```